# Mapnik style editor

Tags: mapnik, style

Is there any tool or editor which can shorten the cycle for experimenting on different styles for mapnik.

It would be wonderful with something like cloudmade's editor, but with the possibility to download the result as xml or cascadenik.

What i want is:

- Short iteration time (ie. few steps and fast generation time for newly changed style) preferably live edit
- Tool which gives help to generate the styles (both graphical tools and word completion would be great alternatives.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/).

It uses gdal to access the geo-data, an editor of [Carto](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/carto/) (a css like language) to stylize your maps, and mapnick to renderize it.

Comment: Tilemill is great. You can even edit in a browser to a remote site without client install:)

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at [Quantumnik](https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/quantumnik/wiki/Home), it is a plugin for QGIS. You create the styles with QGIS and Quantumnik will generate the mapnik xml stylesheet.

Comment: Quantumnik seemed great, but i've had some problems getting it to work. Probably just me, and some conflicting versions (mapnik 2 vs 0.7.x).